# R: While-loop produces numeric with unclear value

Tags: r, while-loop

I have created a while-loop in R which finds the smallest proportion of a given area which is needed to produce a set overall production (prodTarget) under the condition that productivity/ha is not larger than a maximum productivity.

The while-loop itself works fine and does exactly what it is supposed to do, the problem occurs after the loop where I create a sequence from the minimum proportion (as given by the while-loop) to 1. In cases where the minimum proportion found by the while-loop is 1, the seq() command returns an error (First version in the code below). However, seq(1,1,0.1) manually works fine and returns 1 as expected.

```
conservation_Yield<-8.4 # set minimal Yield/ha
max_current_Yield<-173.1 # the maximum observed Yield/ha
Area <- 226.02 # the area in ha

min_target <- conservation_Yield*Area
max_target <- max_current_Yield*Area
prodTargets <- seq(min_target,max_target,Area) # set a range of production targets

# Start loop over all production targets (166 in total, the last two loops are the problem)
for (i in 165: length(prodTargets)){

  currentTarget <- prodTargets[i]
  # Define the range of proportion managed land from the minimum feasable (given the target and maximum productivity) 
  #          to maximum possible

  min_proportion <- 0 # to find the minimum feasable, we set the proportion to zero
  control_Yield <- max_current_Yield*10 # set to arbitrary higher value as max possible yield

  while (control_Yield > max_current_Yield){
    min_proportion <- min_proportion+0.01 # increase the proportion of managed land
    rest_productivity <- currentTarget-conservation_Yield*Area*(1-min_proportion)
    control_Yield <- rest_productivity/(Area*min_proportion)
  }

  max_proportion <- 1 # the maximum possible proportion is always 1

  # First version: works fine for all loops except where min_proportion has to be 1 as well
  landsparing_scenarios <- seq(min_proportion,max_proportion,0.01) # returns an error

  # Second version: Check if min_proportion == 1 and create a vector of 1 manually
    if (min_proportion == 1) { # returns FALSE even though min_proportion is 1
    landsparing_scenarios <- 1
  } else {
    landsparing_scenarios <- seq(min_proportion,max_proportion,0.01)

  }

  # Third version: Check if min_proportion > 0.99 and create a vector of 1 manually
  if (min_proportion > 0.99) {
    landsparing_scenarios <- 1
  } else {
    landsparing_scenarios <- seq(min_proportion,max_proportion,0.01)

  }

}
```

I added an if-else clause to check if the minimum proportion equals 1 (Second version). Now, even though min_proportion returns a numeric 1 when typed in the console, the command min_proportion==1 returns FALSE.
How is it possible that the variable seems to be 1 and the logical operator disagrees?

Comment: Most likely, this is due to rounding. Consider the output of `print(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), digits=16)`. You may consider using `?all.equal` rather than `==`.

Comment: @lmo : Thanks for pointing out that it would be good to look at all the digits. I also suspected a rounding error, but I did not expect to find one after adding 0.01 to a number.

Answer (score 0):

During the while-loop, the value of 0.01 was added at each iteration to the minimum proportion. Although the output of min_proportion suggested that the last step in the loop was `min_proportion = 0.99+0.01`, the resulting number was larger than 1 at the 16th digit.

Trying to create a sequence with `seq(min_proportion,1,0.01)` resulted in an error because min_proportion is in fact 1.000000000000001 which is larger than 1, hence this sequence is not possible. This is also the reason why the test `min_proportion == 1` returned `FALSE`, but the test `min_proportion > 0.99` returned `TRUE`.

One possible solution is to round the variable min_proportion to 2 digits after the while-loop. Another possibility (as pointed out by @lmo) is to use the function `all.equal(min_proportion, 1)` which is less strict than `==`.